# ¿Como obtener la direccion de una celda activa dentro de un ciclo for? VB.NET (EXCEL/INTEROP)

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

Miren tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo un programa en vb.net que lee un libro y analiza cuantas hojas tiene, columnas, tipos y detecta errores en cuanto a tipo (ejemplo, si existe un dato en una celda de tipo texto dentro de una columna numerica). Estoy teniendo problemas con el tipo de dato "fecha" ya que por ejemplo, si en una columna de fechas esta un dato de tipo texto, el programa me devuelve esa casilla como vacia (DBNull), hice las pruebas con msgBox y descubri tal cosa.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al momento de detectar un error (o DBNull) en la columnas con fechas, esta me devuelva la direccion de la celda donde actualmente esta (Si en C10,C40,C2,C2223... ETC), esto me serviria un millon ya que solamente paso como parametro la direccion de la celda a mi metodo de sustitucion y ya lograria lo que deseo. Asi esta actualmente mi funcion de deteccion de errores (Sin referencias del interop actualmente)...

```
Protected Friend Function obtenerErroresColumna(ByVal columna As String, ByVal hoja As String, ByVal tipo As String) As Integer
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna)) Then
        Dim cmd As String = "Select [" & columna & "] from [" & hoja & "$]"
        Dim errores As Integer = 0
        Dim celdas As Integer = 1
        Dim tabla As New DataTable
        Try
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexion)
            adapter.Fill(tabla)
            adapter.Dispose()
            For Each itm In tabla.Rows
                celdas += 1
                If (tipo.Equals("Cadena")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipo.Equals("Numerico")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsNumeric(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf (tipo.Equals("Fecha")) Then
                    If (Not IsDBNull(itm(0))) Then
                        If (Not IsDate(itm(0))) Then
                            errores += 1
                            setValoresError = itm(0)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            tabla.Dispose()
            Return errores
        Catch ex As Exception
            cajaMensaje("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
            PantallaPrincipal.lbldireccion.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Return errores
        End Try
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Si conocen alguna manera de como obtener eso?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Excel.Range rango = (Excel.Range)AplicacionExcel.ActiveCell;
int numeroRow = rango.Row;
int numeroColumn = rango.Column;
```

Acá te dejo otra solución que te puede servir

```
int numeroRow = sheet.Cells.Row;
int numeroColumn = sheet.Cells.Colum;
```

Comment: Genial, esta info es muy util! se me ha ocurrido algo! solamente tendria que obtener la letra de la columna... !

Comment: @TwoDent Si te sirvió la respuesta no te olvides de marcarla con el tilde, saludos!